# Styling controls in a single table cell from the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic table where I add controls. When I open this page in Firefox the controls are unerneath each other and in Internet expl. they are horizontally aligned.
How can I set the style of this controls from the code behind?

```
tabCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center; // doesn't seem to work



ibtnTableOneNew.Command += eventHandelerTableOne;
        ibtnTableOneNew.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        ibtnTableOneNew.CommandArgument = i.ToString() + "|" + theRow["siteAlias"].ToString();
        ibtnTableOneNew.ImageUrl = "~/img/bullet_toggle_plus.png";
        tabCell.Controls.Add(ibtnTableOneNew);

        tabCell.Controls.Add(cbChecked);

        ibtnTableOneNewComment.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        ibtnTableOneNewComment.ImageUrl = "~/img/Pencil.png";
        tabCell.Controls.Add(ibtnTableOneNewComment);

        tabRow.Cells.Add(tabCell);
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't because your table width is to small? I don't think any of the controls you adding would render on the next line.

Comment: But Why is it too small in Firefox when its good in IE?

Comment: try setting tabCell.Wrap = false

Comment: It works! Thanks! Put it in an answer and I'll give you credit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `tabCell.Wrap = false`. That should do what you need.